# Nullpointerexception when using listview and Arrayadapter

Tags: nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter, android-dialog

Hi i am trying to populate the calendar events into a dailog with  listview, while setting the adapter to listview i am getting nullpointerexception . below is my code

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                           dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list_view);
                            dialog.setTitle("Events");

                              ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_view,R.id.text,desc);//desc your string array 
                              myList.setAdapter(ad);
```

Below is my layout xml file

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

         <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mylist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="#b5b5b5"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

Not sure where am i doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dialog = new Dialog(your_activity.this);
```

Also declare it globally..